# Тесты джанго: тест пагинатора

Tags: python, django

При перемещении теста из отдельного класса в класс с остальными тестами, начинает показывать на второй странице 4 поста вместо 3ех. Если range изменить на 12 то показывает 2 поста. Прошу подсказать в чем проблема.

```
def test_correct_page_context_guest_client(self):
    """
    Проверяем работу пагинатора.
    """

    posts = [Post(text=f'Тестовый текст {i}',
                  group=self.group0,
                  author=self.user0) for i in range(
        13)]
    Post.objects.bulk_create(posts)
    pages = (reverse('posts:posts_list'),
             reverse('posts:group_list',
                     kwargs={'slug': f'{self.group0.slug}'}),
             reverse('posts:profile',
                     kwargs={'username': f'{self.user0.username}'}))
    for page in pages:
        for page_number in range(2):
            with self.subTest(page=page):
                response = self.guest_client0.get(
                    page, {'page': page_number+1})
                self.assertEqual(len(response.context['page_obj']),
                                 POSTS_COUNT[page_number])
```

Answer (score 0):

Мешал пост созданный в SetUpClass. Удалить его перед тестом паджинатора и не сломать остальные тесты помогло перемещение этого поста в SetUp. В тесте паджинатора удалил его self.post.delete()